# Proper way to optimize a multi-DB web application

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli, query-optimization

I am currently building a web application that will be using two databases at the same time. The user first creates a general account and afterwards uses it to create multiple characters on multiple 'servers'. (think of it as creating an account on Facebook and then using it to sign up on other websites).

My current database setup is the following:

- `main_english`
- `main_russian`
- `server1`
- `server2`
- `server3`

The `main_english` and `main_russian` databases contain the **session and general account data** for users who've registered at the appropriate languages.

The `server1` and `server2` databases handle the created character data of the English users, while `server3` handles the Russian ones.

Users will be updating tables every 5-10 seconds or so. My question is, how could I efficiently handle having several DBs used?

**So far I've come to several options:**

1. Open two DB connections: one for `main_` and another for `server`,
   but I've read that opening them is fairly expensive.
2. Modifying all
   my queries to explicitly state which DB to update/select data from
   (the project is still young and thus it wouldn't be **that**
   painful)
3. Modifying my $db class to have `select_db()` statements
   with each query, which, in my opinion, is both messy and
   inefficient.

What could *you* suggest? Perhaps I am overreacting about opening a second connection for the `server` queries?

Comment: I'd be a bit more worried about handling cross-database transactions.  Or isn't that a concern for your use case?

Comment: Thanks, in my case, it won't be of any of any concern at all since the databases are fairly nonindependent in regards to each other.

Comment: independent* sorry only noticed the typo when I couldn't edit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is known to have fast connection handling so thats unlikely to be a bottleneck. That being said you could look into persistent connections in the `PDO` or `mysqli` extensions.

In terms of the server access and data modeling its difficult to say without knowing more about your application. How do DB slaves factor in? Is replication lag OK?

Comment: The databases are fairly independent in regards to each other. No changes to `server_` change `main_` and vice-versa. I can't say anything about replication lag yet as I haven't actually tried anything out yet, the project is in its **early** development state.